# PySpark DataFrame Filter Column Contains Multiple Value

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Just wondering if there are any efficient ways to filter columns contains a list of value,  e.g:

Suppose I want to filter a column contains beef, Beef:

I can do:

```
beefDF=df.filter(df.ingredients.contains('Beef')|df.ingredients.contains('beef'))
```

Instead of doing the above way, I would like to create a list:

```
beef_product=['Beef','beef']
```

and do:

```
beefDF=df.filter(df.ingredients.contains(beef_product))
```

I don't need to maintain code but just need to add new beef (e.g ox, ribeyes) in the beef_product list to have the filter dataframe.

Obviously the contains function do not take list type, what is a good way to realize this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with **`.isin()`** accepts `list`.

```
beefDF=df.filter(df.ingredients.isin(beef_product))
```

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,'beef'),(2,'Beef'),(3,'b')],['id','ingredients'])

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
beef_product=['Beef','beef']
df.filter(df.ingredients.isin(beef_product)).show()
#+---+-----------+
#| id|ingredients|
#+---+-----------+
#|  1|       beef|
#|  2|       Beef|
#+---+-----------+
```

Comment: I believe this doesn't answer the question as the .isin() method looks for exact matches instead of looking if a string contains a value

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,'beef'),(2,'Beef'),(3,'Cow'), (3,'Tiger')],  
                         ['id','ingredients'])
df.filter("ingredients in ('Beef','Tiger')").show()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.